# how to ignore the immediate parent which is of specific type in hierarchical query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have below tables definition.As  I need to ignore the immediate parent which is of type 'Package';other types can also exists in the tables.

For example when I pass CHILD_NODE_ID= 3289374 to the query,the immediate parent_id is 3289375 but it  is of 'Folder' type so ignored it from the hierarchical query itself and next parent id 3289376 which is of type Package should also be ignored from the result set as per my requirement.

I am only interested in Package types.My query also will fetch only Package types but its not ignoring immediate parent which is of type 'Package'.

Hierarchical  query should  recursively check only Package Types and should produce final result as '3289373'.

```
CHILD_NODE          
******************          
ID  PARENT_NODE_ID  CHILD_NODE_ID       ISBN
2314861 3289375     3289374             9780838474648
2314862 3289376     3289375             folder_name
2314863 3289373     3289376             9780838473559
2314864 1271271     3289373             9780838441473



NODE        
***********     
ID      Type    
3289374 Package 
3289375 Folder  
3289376 Package 
3289373 Package 


SELECT *

                    FROM CHILD_NODE c, NODE n 
                         WHERE
                          c.CHILD_NODE_ID=N.ID AND
                           N.TYPE='Package'
                                    START WITH CHILD_NODE_ID=3289374
                                    CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_NODE_ID = CHILD_NODE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot exclude the 'Folder' type building the hierarchy. Doing so terminates the hierarchy as there would be no Prior id. So one approach is to build the hierarchy in a CTE then eliminate Folder in the selecting from the CTE.

```
with hier as 
   ( select c.id, c.parent_node_id, c.child_node_id, n.type, level                                          
       from child_node c                       
       join node       n  on c.child_node_id=n.id                                             
      start with c.child_node_id=3289374               
    connect by prior c.parent_node_id = c.child_node_id
   )
select * from hier where type <> 'Folder';
```

However, be careful removing levels from the heirarchy if you plan using it further. I added the level to show this. Notice there is no level 2.

Comment: 3289374 value will come from outer table so WITH clause wont work it here.it says invalid identifier.

Comment: There is no outer table there. An inner join in the  CTE and a select from the that.